# jquery toggle form into div and no response on submission

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a comment with reply button on a product page.

all comments are fetching from db (ajax called) into certain div block when page is loaded, please note there is a `reply` button for each comment and `<div class="quickReplyForm"></div>` is suppose to show the reply form once the `reply` button is clicked.

**load comments (ajax)**

```
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){

    $msg .= '
            <div class="bs-callout bs-callout-info">
                <h5><b>'.$row['name'].'</b> <small>'.date('M d, Y @ h:i A', strtotime($row['date'])).'</small></h5>
                <p>'.$row['comment'].'</p>
                <p><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success btn_reply" data-name="'.$row['name'].'" data-id="'.$row['id'].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span> Reply</button></p>
                <div class="quickReplyForm"></div>
            </div>';
}
```

here is **reply form** which is preset and hidden in top of the page ready to trigger and show inside `<div class="quickReplyForm"></div>` block:

```
<div class="row reply_form" style="display:none;">
<div class="col-md-6">
<form role="form" id="reply_form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="message">
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btn_reply_comment">Reply Comment</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

then in jquery:

```
$('body').on('click','.btn_reply',function(){

    var id = $(this).data('id'); //get the `id` from data property
    var name = $(this).data('name');
    //alert(id + "/" + name);

    $(this).after('<div class="quickReplyForm">'+$(".reply_form").html()+'</div>');

});
```

my **first question** is, the form is displayed in each of the `<div class="quickReplyForm"></div>` block when `reply` button is clicked, but the form will keeps shown up for each time reply button is clicked, how can it be avoid? and how to properly shown up the form inside its 'body'?

[image]

**EDITED**

**second question**, the form doesn't post the input parameters, the alert of parameters is return `message={empty}`?

```
$('body').on('click','#btn_reply_comment',function(){
    var parameters = $('#reply_form').serialize();
    alert(parameters);

});
```

[image]

Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st answer:** You need to hide form before show reply form;

```
$('body').on('click','.btn_reply',function(){
    // Hide previous form
    $(".quickReplyForm").remove();
    var id = $(this).data('id'); //get the `id` from data property
    var name = $(this).data('name');
    $("#comment_id").val(id);
    //alert(id + "/" + name);

    $(this).after('<div class="quickReplyForm">'+$(".reply_form").html()+'</div>');

});
```

And another importan point, you need to update `id` and `name` field of reply form on each opened form. Or else, you save comment on wrong comment

**2nd answer:** In your second case you need to use delegate structure;

```
$('body').on('click','#btn_reply_comment',function(){
    var parameters = $(this).closest('#reply_form').serialize();
    alert(parameters);
    // ajax here
});
```

Here is a working demo for 2nd answer: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/THE9j/)**

**Edit:**

In order to add id to comment form,

You can do that by adding a hidden form to `.reply_form` like;

```
<div class="row reply_form" style="display:none;">
<div class="col-md-6">
<form role="form" id="reply_form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="message">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="comment_id" value=""/>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btn_reply_comment">Reply Comment</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

And then, before opening form you can call;

```
$("#comment_id").val(id);
```

Comment: pls see my edited post for second question if you could help?

Comment: i overlook this `var parameters = $(this).closest('#reply_form').serialize();`, works now! thanks

Comment: by the way, how could I pass data-id `var id = $(this).data('id');` to  the form?

Comment: doesn't get it to work, I've been using `append()` -> `$(this).after('<div class="quickReplyForm">'+$('#reply_form').append("<input type='hidden' name='parent_id' value='"+id+"'><input type='hidden' name='reply-to' value='"+name+"'>")+$(".reply_form").html()+'</div>');`. the params can be pass thru alert but I saw `[object Object]` are auto populated on top of the form?

Comment: In your question there is only `$(this).after('<div class="quickReplyForm">'+$(".reply_form").html()+'</div>');` That is why I have used above code. could you please try my original code? Because, I am adding id to hidden form, and then get updated form

Comment: I have been tried what you're updated, it seems doesn't alert `comment_id` at all? maybe I have something miss out? please wait, I will update my post in short while

Comment: oppss, my miss out again, i forget to add `name="comment_id"` in the hidden input, I will test again and let you know here